# How can a photon bouncing between two mirrors on a moving train illustrate perceived time dilation?

Tags: time-dilation

An outside observer couldn't see it; there would have to be a photon - a stream of photons - emitted back from that bouncing photon to the observer's eye or measuring device - absurd.  Or the photon would have to be in two places at once - also absurd.  Doesn't this familiar thought-experiment illegitimately conflate two radically different things: what an all-knowing theorist, outside of the hypothesized scenario, can *conceive* with what a situated observer could actually *perceive*?  Conception relies upon *imagination*, not perception.

Answer (score 2):

The photons are not important. The light clock is just an illustration. The important thing is the speed. As long as there is an invariant speed the time dilation follows. It doesn’t matter if anything actually travels at that speed. Nor does it matter if an actual device like a light clock can be built. The geometry of the light clock correctly analyzes the required time dilation if there is an invariant speed. All else is irrelevant

> An outside observer couldn't see it; there would have to be a photon - a stream of photons - emitted back from that bouncing photon to the observer's eye or measuring device - absurd.

Even if this objection were relevant, it would also be incorrect. There is no need for an outside observer to see the bouncing pulse of light itself. A detector in the clock can detect it and provide any external indication necessary. The bouncing light can remain entirely within the light clock.

Comment: This thought-experiment can be found in an article by Harvard Professor Peter Galison, at https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:HarvardX+EMC2x+2T2021/block-v1:HarvardX+EMC2x+2T2021+type@sequential+block@8e1f0a88782e4c81840002ef36a7bc4c/block-v1:HarvardX+EMC2x+2T2021+type@vertical+block@5429ddf0a76e47b28af2494169b699cd.   If "the photons are not important" there would be no way to rigorously derive the precise formula for 'gamma', the Lorentz factor, which establishes time dilation.  Far from being unimportant, they are absolutely critical.

Comment: It really is not critical at all. Again, this is purely about spacetime geometry, so you can use a completely hypothetical classical object which travels at c in the derivation. Whether or not such an object actually exists doesn't impact the derivation one iota.

Comment: This is like saying that reality doesn't matter.  Even if there is no light clock which can actually be SEEN, as long as you can somehow derive your thesis from "spacetime", that's sufficient.

Comment: @SumwunYumaynotno said “This is like saying that reality doesn't matter” That is a rubbish complaint. Your favorite derivation doesn’t include the brand of paint used to paint the light clock. That is part of reality, so why not include it too? Not every aspect of reality is important for every proof. Here the **only** important aspect is the existence of an invariant speed. All of the objections you bring in your question are as irrelevant as the paint. Relativity would still hold even if all particles had mass and therefore nothing could travel at the invariant speed.

Comment: Then please show me the correct derivation, or direct me to where it can be found.

Comment: Sure. The first one here is my favorite https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591218/how-to-explain-time-dilation-without-light-clock

Comment: That's true, but that's not a derivation; it's just an assertion. If you took a look at that article by Galison that I mentioned earlier, you would see HOW that formula comes about from the postulate of the constant speed of light, the moving pair of mirrors, the oscillating photon, the right triangle that it traces out, and the Pythagorean theorem.  That mathematical formula is a RESULT of those factors.  If you ignore it, that makes you ignorant. I don't want to waste my time or yours any more.

Comment: It is a derivation, just starting from a different premise. My approach to relativity is to start with the invariance of the spacetime interval and derive everything from that. But if you prefer Einstein’s postulates then you can derive the Lorentz transform from them and then show the invariance of the spacetime interval and then do my part of the derivation, all w/o a light clock. Anyway, I don’t feel that my time has been wasted. I am sad that you feel that asking for and receiving an expert opinion was a waste, simply because the expert disagreed with your non-expert objection.